# Android DialogFragment not wrapping text in Portuguese

Tags: android

The problem I'm having is that the text in a `DialogFragment` won't wrap in Portuguese, even though it does in Spanish. I don't really know what's causing it. It's the same basic code for `DialogFragment` creation:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_save_personal_info)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // save user info
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.label_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // Do nothing, dialog will dismiss itself
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

The dialog is coming out like this is Spanish:
[image: Spanish dialog]

And the Portuguese one is coming like this:
[image: Portuguese dialog]

The "deseja" is not being word-wrapped down... does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I believe this is default behaviour. Your Portugese translation has shorter words, so "desej" fits on the first line, while Spanish version doesn't. Why should this be a problem?

Comment: @curtisLoew First of all, thanks for your response! The Spanish version is word-wrapping "guardar" down, instead of displaying guar`\n`dar. Even though the "a" doesn't fit in Portuguese, it should wrap the whole word down (regardless of the length of the words in the translation), like it did for "guardar" in Spanish.